# Novice Python/Regex: pull strings between <a> tags using regex

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Need to pull strings between href attribute tags in Python using the re module.

I've tried numerous patterns such as:

```
patFinderLink = re.compile('\>"(CVE.*)"\<\/a>')
```

Example: I need to pull what is between the tags (in this case "**CVE-2010-3718**") from:

```
<pre>
<a href="https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/CVE-2010-3718.html">CVE-2010-3718</a>
</pre>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Sun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised no one suggested to use BeautifulSoup:

here is how I would do it :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

hello = """
<pre>
<a href="https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/CVE-2010-3718.html">CVE-2010-3718</a>
<a href="https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/CVE-2010-3710.html">CVE-2010-3718</a>
<a href="https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/CVE-2010-3700.html">CVE-2010-3718</a>
</pre>
"""

target = re.compile("CVE-\d+-\d+.html")
commentSoup = BeautifulSoup(hello)
atags = commentSoup.findAll(href=target)
for a in atags:
    match = re.findall(target, a['href'])[0]
    print match
```

Result:

```
CVE-2010-3718.html
CVE-2010-3710.html
CVE-2010-3700.html
```

Comment: Although the other answers propose perhaps more elegant solutions, this one worked for me in a pinch.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Do you need to use regex? I don't think you do, you can't parse SGML with regular expressions because SGML itself is not regular, see this famous stackoverflow answer for the reasoning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/88123

Anyhow. You should use the `lxml` Python module and its xpath implementation. `xpath` supports selecting with text that starts with.

XPath in this case would be `//h1/text()`.

Or, use the `BeautifulSoup` Python module.

Comment: +1 for lxml and I'd give another +1 for the famous anti-reg-exp answer!

Comment: @Acorn - I actually looked at the page he linked and saw the CVE number expressed in the h1.

Comment: The reason for regular expressions causing people two problems is exactly this. They use them where they do not apply.

Comment: @ikanobori The linked answer is famous for its literary quality, but that veils what he wants to express exactly. Does he employ 'parse' to precisely mean "the process of extracting a tree representation of the text" ? In this case, I can trust him: regexes can't do that for the reason he explains. But that must not lead all the earth's people to religiously believe that regexes can NEVER been used to **ANALYZE** a text. The word 'parse' is now generally used as meaning 'analyze' but it seems to me that in computer science it formerly meant only 'extracting a tree' (?) That's a pitiful mess

Comment: The reason for not parsing HTML (in this case specifically) with regular expressions is that HTML is not regular. If you are consuming (scraping) a third party maintained site and things change you'll have more work on a practical level if you employ regular expressions (and they are harder to maintain). HTML is, sadly, not regular (it doesn't even define which tags to be closed (self-closing, etc)). All in all, a simple answer is: "don't use regular expressions to parse html" but the true depths of the answer are more of a gray area.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to use regular expressions to parse HTML or XML. Use a parser such as [`lxml`](http://lxml.de).

```py
import lxml.html as lh

tree = lh.fromstring(html)

print tree.xpath("//pre/a[starts-with(., 'CVE')]/text()")
```

**Result:**

```
['CVE-2010-3718']
```

Comment: _lxml_ is at least 20 times slower than a regex. In fact I measured 100 times one day, but it may be not representative of the medium excess of time of  _lxml_ solutions compared to regex solutions, so I prefer to say 20.....

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
re.compile('">(CVE.*?)</a>') 

# instead of your re.compile('\>"(CVE.*)"\<\/a>')
```

Note that characters < > / don't need to be escaped in a regex pattern

And note that the `?` character after `.*` stops the greedy behavior of the quantifier `*` in order that the match stops when the first `</a>` is encoutered. See the docs on this point, it is fundamental

.

Sometimes there are problems when using `re` to analyze a XML|GML text
Once, I was told that one possible problem is that a tag can be written on several lines,  for example:

```
ss = '''
<pre>
    <a href="https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/CVE-2010-3718.html">CVE-20
    10-371
    8</a>
</pre>'''
```

In this case, there won't be any match because the dot used as symbol in a regex's pattern doesnt symbolize the newline '\n'. So the portion `.*?` of the pattern won't allow to run from line to line.

To correct this problem, use the `re.DOTALL` specification that gives to the dot symbol the power to represent any and all characters.

.

Note that the common conviction is that the **re** tool must not be used to parse a SGML or XML text. But few people are able to explain thoroughly why. And I am one of these people who don't know precisely why.

But personally, I think that regular expression can be used to analyze texts indeed. I write 'ANALYZE' not 'PARSE'.

As far as I understood, parsing is the process of analyzing a text AND building a tree representation of it based on the tags.
While I define analyzing a text as ... analyzing it without the aim to obtain a tree representation.
When a tree representation isn't necessary to extract data from a text, use regular expressions, and don't listen guys that have religious considerations on the subject like in the funny but deceiving (in my opinion) post whose link has been given

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use regexps for HTML parsing (while it's not recommended as was alredy mentioned - but I don't know why) try this:

```
a = re.compile('<a href=".*">(.*)</a>')
result = a.match(string).group(0)
```

the result will contain CVE-2010-3718

Answer (score 0):

As others have already suggested, regular expressions are often not a good tool for HTML parsing.

But if you want to use regexp, this is an example of how i would extract all tuples of both URLs and content between the `<a> </a>` tags:

```
import re

#example html string with various hits
html_string = """
    <pre>
    <a href="https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/CVE-2010-3718.html">CVE-2010-3718</a>
    <a href="https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/CVE-2010-3710.html">CVE-2010-3710</a>
    <a href="https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/CVE-2010-3700.html">CVE-2010-3700</a>
    </pre>
"""

#regular expression:
pattern = re.compile('<a href=([^>]*)>([^<]*)</a>')

#find all matches in our html string:
tuples = pattern.findall(html_string)

for tuple in tuples:
    print "%s —> %s" % (tuple[1], tuple[0])
```

As others mentioned, lxml would be a more suitable tool.

If you are going to do it this way, i recommend you to follow the @Acorn reply.